# The induced subgraph with the highest number of edges has e edges. What should e be at least?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider a (simple undirected) graph G = (V, E) with 12 vertices and 56 edges. Arbitrarily
partition the set of 12 vertices V into three equally sized sets of 4 vertices V1, V2, and V3,
and denote G1, G2, and G3 as the subgraphs induced by V1, V2, and V3, respectively. The
induced subgraph with the highest number of edges has e edges. What should e be at least?

The question above is for my homework, but I am unsure how to count the least edges. So far I have:

$V_{1} = \{{e_{11}, e_{12}, e_{13}, e_{14}}\}$,
$V_{2} = \{{e_{21}, e_{22}, e_{23}, e_{24}}\}$,
$V_{3} = \{{e_{31}, e_{32}, e_{33}, e_{34}}\}$.

How would I make the subgraphs and find the least amount of edges? I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I'll get you started.  Since we want to make the induced subgraphs have as few edges as possible, we want as many edges as possible to join vertices in different sets. Let there be an edge joining every pair of vertices in two different sets.  That gives $8$ edges per vertex, or $48$ edges in all, and there are in total $8$ edges belonging to the induced subgraphs.

Can you finish it?

Comment: So what I ended up doing is making three subgraphs with with four vertices and connected them. It total I had 14 edges. Is that correct way to go about it?

Comment: @MichaelD I don't understand what you mean.  You should have $56$ edges in total, and $8$ in all the induced subgraphs put together.  What are the $14$ edges?